# JavaScript Regex - trying to match all numbers in (5', 78', 80')(90'+2') Not preceded by +

Tags: javascript, regex, negative-lookbehind

I've got some soccer goal information represented like this:

(5', 78', 80')(90'+2')

I would like to use javascript to match all the numbers *not* preceded by a `+` sign (the 2 in this case).  I don't know how to do this without negative lookbehinds.

I've tried this:

```
"(5', 78', 80')(90'+2')".match(/[^+]\d+'/g)
```

but I get parenthesis, spaces, and `'` in my returned matches:

```
["(5'", " 78'", " 80'", "(90'"]
```

I'm looking for a result like.  Note it doesn't have the number `2` in it, because 2 is preceded with a `+`

```
["5", "78", "80", "90"]
```

Any pointers is appreciated.

Comment: First thought: remove numbers preceded by +, then you can match all numbers.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?  This is definitely the simplest solution!  Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a single regexp, or can you work with bits of JS to do pre- and post-filtering?

Comment: *but I get parenthesis, spaces, and ' in my returned matches* Why not just remove them?

Comment: I can use as much js as I want.  For curiosities sake, a single regex would be interesting to learn from, but I'll probably implement the simplest solution.

Comment: you can use : / [^+](\d+)/g  https://regex101.com/r/wT7kM8/4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a captured group for the value you want in result:

```
var regexp = /(?:\+\d+|(\d+))'/g;
var str = "(5', 78', 80')(90'+2')";
var m;
var result = [];

while ((m = regexp.exec(str))) {
   if (m[1] !== undefined)
      result.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(result);
//=> ["5", "78", "80", "90"]
```

Comment: Clever!  Using a capture group inside a non capturing group.  Learned something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use this pattern

```
(?:[^+]|^)(\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/385)